# Redis failover between primary/primary regions on Azure (.net)

Tags: .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

Using stackexchange redis library in .net7.

Redis Enterprise on Azure - North Europe + UK South.

Redis set up as two clusters (primary / primary) across the regions with georeplication.

All services connect to NE, if NE is out we want to failover to UKS (and visa versa).

The library allows us to add both instances to the configuration, but they have to share a password (which we can't do).

Apparently redis sentinel can't be used in our Azure.

When microservices connect to their regional redis clusters we've experienced race conditions where two services are able to alter the redis data at roughly the same time due to georeplication latency.

Coding a manual failover would rely on timeouts to determine whether a connection is down; this would cause unacceptable delays which could have knock-on effects.

Is there a better way of doing this?  How have other people solved this problem?